# Graphics overlay jlabel image Icon

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jlabel, imageicon

I'm doing a game in java, and my problem is setting the background.
I've tried using `g.drawImage()` but as its repaints every time, cause fps to drop a lot. So i fixed this fps issue by setting background with `JLabel` and `ImageIcon`. But the label overlay the graphics, how can I fix this?

```
public class GameScreen extends Screen implements Observer {

private static GameScreen gamescreen;
private Game game;
private JLabel label = new JLabel();
private ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("./res/img/bg1.png");

private GameScreen() {
    setGame(Game.getInstance());

    setLayout(null);
    label.setIcon(icon);
    label.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 600);
    
    add(label);
}

public static GameScreen getInstance() {
    if(getGameScreen() == null) {
        setGameScreen(new GameScreen());
    }
    return getGameScreen();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    
    //PaintWorld
    new DrawableWorld().draw(g, getWidth(), getHeight());
    //Paint players
    new DrawablePlayer().draw(g, getWidth(), getHeight(), getGame().getPlayers());
    //Paint hud
    new DrawableHud().draw(g, getWidth(), getGame().getPlayers());
}

@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    repaint();
}
//getters & setters..
```

Example:
[image: Example]

PS: All DrawableClasses extends Screen that extends JPanel

Comment: Try to use [BackgroundPanel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/)

Comment: Happens the same, it overlays the graphics :(

Answer (score 1):

g.drawImage is a very fast (to an extent) operation. Do you scale the image while drawing? Do you use "maximum quality" rendering hints?

Comment: yeh, getScaledInstance(getWidth(),getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)

Comment: So scale it once, save to a new image and draw this new image only.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: How I scale the image to current width/height outside the paintComponent?

Comment: Create some static variables Image, Width, Height - if width&height are the same, use the Image, if not - rescale, set variables with the new values.

Comment: Thank you man, now its working right. i'll post code if someone need this as example

Comment: `Create some static variables` Don't use static variables. The variables are properties of this class and should not be static.

Answer (score 0):

Following [@serg.nechaev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/655249/serg-nechaev) answer.

```
    public class GameScreen extends Screen implements Observer {

private static GameScreen gamescreen;
private Game game;
//New static vars
private static BufferedImage image;
private static Image img;
private static int w = 0;
private static int h = 0;

private GameScreen() {
    setGame(Game.getInstance());
    setImage();
}

public static GameScreen getInstance() {
    if(getGameScreen() == null) {
        setGameScreen(new GameScreen());
    }
    return getGameScreen();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //Scaling once
    if(w != getWidth() || h != getHeight()) {
        img = getImage().getScaledInstance(getWidth(), getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        w = getWidth();
        h = getHeight();    
    }
    else{
        g.drawImage(getImg(), 0, 0, this);  
    }

    //PaintWorld
    new DrawableWorld().draw(g, getWidth(), getHeight());
    //Paint players
    new DrawablePlayer().draw(g, getWidth(), getHeight(), getGame().getPlayers());
    //Paint hud
    new DrawableHud().draw(g, getWidth(), getGame().getPlayers());
}

@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    repaint();
}
//getters & setters..
    public BufferedImage getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage() {
    try {
        GameScreen.image = ImageIO.read(new File("./res/img/bg1.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Image getImg() {
    return GameScreen.img;
}
```

Result with good fps:
[image]

Comment: `Create some static variables` Don't use static variables. The variables are properties of this class and should not be static. Also, why are you creating new classes in the painting method? A painting method should just be for painting, not creating new objects.